# For some pages, Windows Authenticated React website prompts up Sign in window asking username and password

Tags: reactjs, windows-authentication, credential-manager

An intranet website written in React, after users login to laptops they do not need to enter credential again to access the React application, because Windows Authentication automatically provides the authentication for the whole React website. Namely for all web pages, users can easily access them without re-login.

The problem is , there is one user, can access most of the intranet React website pages without problem, but for few specific pages the website prompts that user to enter username and password, those pages invoking fetch method to call an API with these parameters:

> {
> method: "POST",
> body: data,
> credentials: "include", }

Other users do not have this problem.

What could be the reason ? any hint would be highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]